# How do I prevent a UINavigationBar from animating when I push and pop UIViewControllers?

Tags: objective-c, animation, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, pushviewcontroller

I have a custom UINavigationBar set in a UINavigationController. I would like to prevent the NavigationBar from animating when new viewcontrollers are pushed and popped from the NavigationController. Normally, the UINavigationBar animates the title and back button right to left during a push, and left to right during a pop. I would like to stop this functionality, keeping the NavigationBar more or less static.

I can prevent the popping animation by overriding the following in my custom UINavigationBar:

```
-(UINavigationItem *)popNavigationItemAnimated:(BOOL)animated{
    return [super popNavigationItemAnimated:NO];
}
```

However, if I override

```
- (void)pushNavigationItem:(UINavigationItem *)item animated:(BOOL)animated
```

the UINavigationBar still animates whenever I push a new viewcontroller onto the NavigationController.

EDIT: I still want the pushed or popped viewController to animate in or out. It is only the NavigationBar that should be stopped.

Comment: Even after with animated option as NO?

Comment: It doesn't matter if I overload -(void)pushNavigationItem:item animated:animated, because the method is never called when pushing a viewController.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me - override this method on UINavigationBar:

```
- (void)pushNavigationItem:(UINavigationItem *)item {
    NSMutableArray* items = [[self items] mutableCopy];
    [items addObject:item];
    self.items = items;
}
```